# Unable to import 'pytest'

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pylint, pipenv

I want to test for [raise](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions), but getting `Unable to import 'pytest'PylintE0401:import-error` when importing pytest into `test_main.py`.
My environment and editor are correctly configured and pytest installed.

Steps to reproduce:

- Created environment with `pipenv`:

```bash
❯ pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2023.10.24

❯ pipenv shell

❯ pipenv --venv
/user/path/.local/share/virtualenvs/environment-name

❯ which python3
/user/path/.local/share/virtualenvs/environment-name/bin/python3
```

- Correctly configured my editor to use the created virtual environment
- Installed `pipenv install --dev pytest`

```bash
❯ pipenv graph
...
pytest==7.4.4
├── iniconfig [required: Any, installed: 2.0.0]
├── packaging [required: Any, installed: 23.2]
└── pluggy [required: >=0.12,<2.0, installed: 1.3.0]
```

- Pipfile contains `pytest`

```ini
[dev-packages]
pytest = "*"
```

- Contents of `test_main.py`

```py
import pytest


def test_zero_division():
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        1 / 0
```

Am I missing something?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I tried your repro (altho I didn't bother with configuring an editor, I just did everything on the command-line) however I'm afraid it worked for me. I ran pytest by issuing `pipenv run pytest`, output was "1 passed in 0.01s". pipenv version is "2023.11.15".

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your `test_main.py` with this command

`pipenv run python test_main.py`

Doc: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html#using-installed-packages

Comment: I am getting the lint error in the editor, before running the test file